# passing static const attribute of class to a function

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

for an arduino school project where I draw bitmaps to a screen, I want to store said bitmaps as unsigned char arrays in classes.

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
class Actor{
  public:
    static constexpr unsigned char sprite[8] = {0x97, 0xd5, 0xb7, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x4a, 0x44, 0x4a};
};

void setup() {
  Actor a;

  u8g2.begin(); // setup for display
  u8g2.drawXBM(10, 10, 8, 8, a.sprite); // draw bitmap to display buffer
  u8g2.sendBuffer(); // send buffer to display
}
```

which leads to the following error message:

```
/tmp/cc8frii8.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `u8g2_DrawXBM':
/home/pichler/Arduino/libraries/U8g2/src/clib/u8g2_bitmap.c:146: undefined reference to `Actor::sprite'
/home/pichler/Arduino/libraries/U8g2/src/clib/u8g2_bitmap.c:146: undefined reference to `Actor::sprite'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
```

which leads me to believe that somehow the variable "sprite" can't be accessed. Does anyone know why that could be, and how to do it right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't reproduce http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09c739c3ab39887b perhaps issue is in your code that you did not post.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code per se as you posted it. The error tells you that the linker cannot find the (static) instance of sprite. Given the line numbers, I'm assuming these are actually in different files (and maybe libraries)? Make sure you link the library of Actor when you compile u8g2_bitmap.

Comment: May be you compile it in C++11 mode and attempt to take address of sprite? That issue was removed by C++17 so compile in C++17 mode.

Comment: It's quite surprising that the reference apparently occurs in the function `u8g2_DrawXBM`. Line 146 in [this](https://github.com/olikraus/U8g2_Arduino) github repo is `if ( u8g2_IsIntersection(u8g2, x, y, x+w, y+h) == 0 )`. Is that the library you're using?

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, that's the library I use

Comment: @Pichler And what does line 146 of your "u8g2_bitmap.c" say?

Comment: @molbdnilo it's the same. But I already got it to work with the help of Chris Uzdavinis. Thanks anyway, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, you're getting a linker error, not a compile time error.  Everything is fine as far as compilation goes, but you have not done quite enough to satisfy the entire toolchain.  The issue is, you never gave a definition for the variable, and the linker fails to find it when it brings everything together.

This issue would go away if you were compiling with c++ 17.  What is happening is that when you pass `a.sprite` to a function, the array decays to a pointer type (to the first element) and since it must have an address, is considered **odr used**.  This means that the variable must have an unambiguous location in your application, and thus be explicitly declared (like any normal static variable that is odr-used.)

For static members of a class, if they are odr-used, they must be declared in one place in the application, usually in a cpp file:

```
class Foo {
    static constexpr int x;
};

// Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"

// Give a definition so it has a single location
int Foo::x;
```

Compile in this definition with the rest of your application and the problem will go away.

In c++17, constexpr static members are implicitly "inline" variables, which means that a definition will be placed into every object file that sees it, in a way that does not cause duplicate definition errors.  This is analogous to what "inline" means for functions.  As such, from your class declaration alone it can generate the definition for you, and so you do not need the .cpp file as mentioned above if you use c++17 or later.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very new to c++ and don't really understand your answer. Why would I need to include my file in itself? I'm programming for an arduino, so everything is in one file except for the libraries I use

Comment: In normal c++ code, you separate a header file (.hpp) from the implementation file (.cpp).  People wishing to use your code include the header for the declarations (to allow their code to compile), and they link your object code to resolve the symbols (provide definitions to the binary.)  If you only have one cpp file, then you don't need to include anything, but just add the definition _outside_ the class, in similar fashion to what I did in the example.  Or use c++17 if you can.  :)

Comment: I don't see how this could cause a problem in a function defined inside the library. I would expect the missing reference to be the one in `setup`, where the variable iis used.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis @molbdnilo Thank you for taking time out of your day to answer me! I tried to add `unsigned char Actor::sprite[8]` right below and outside the class but I got this error: "conflicting declaration 'unsigned char Actor::sprite' "

Comment: don't forget to say "constexpr" when you define it outside the class.   https://godbolt.org/z/TYM5KM

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis holy cannoli, it works! Thank you so so much!